# How to copy recursive directory structure while creating symbolic file links only?

Tags: unix, directory, copy, symlink

What's the best way to copy a whole recursive directory structure where all files are just copied as symbolic links?

In other words, the copy should mirror the whole directory (sub-)structure of the original directory but each file should just be a symbolic link.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Are you familiar with `find` and `ln`?

Comment: And can you provide a small example of what you're after, so if someone does come up with something, they'll at least go in the same direction you intend?  I'm assuming you'd want directories as directories?

Comment: Also -- are you sure this is what you want to do? This would mean that any modifications to files would be seen in both directories, but any *new* files or directories would not be shared, and any *deleted* files or directories would result in broken symlinks. So the two directories would have an odd mixture of in-synch and not. Normally people either use `ln` at the top-level so the two directories are symlinked and completely in-synch, or else use `cp` recursively so that the two directories are completely independent afterward.

Comment: +1 for @ruakh ... this sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What problem are you trying to solve?  What are you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: I've used a system that does this for installing a reference copy of the software once, and then creating multiple working installations (which contain a mixture of configuration and data files mixed in with the non-changing software) using symlinks to refer to the reference copy.  The trick is to ensure that you create real directories and appropriate symbolic links.  But the script I use is 340-odd lines; 110 of them comment or blank lines.

Comment: The use case is that I have a lot of files in a directory and in subdirectories. I pass the name of the top-level directory to a program that processes all the data. Now I want to make a copy of that directory structure and change one of the files somewhere in there and run the program again. But I don't actually want to make a full copy because its size is 100s of GBs. Instead, I want to create a copy of the directory structure filled with appropriate symlinks. After that, I can go into that structure and remove one of the symlinks and replace it with my new content and rerun the program.

Comment: Ah, you've got a large torrent file you want to keep seeding, but also seed to another tracker that bundled the same content with a different .nfo file.  Makes sense.

Comment: I see this was closed. Can someone suggest a more appropriate stack exchange site to post this to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess ... first you want to make your directories...

```
cd "$source"
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$target/{}" \;
```

Next, make your symlinks...

```
cd "$source"
find . -type f -print | (
    cd "$target"
    while read one; do
        deep=$(echo "${one:2}" | sed 's:[^/][^/]*:..:g')
        ln -s "${deep:3}/${one:2}" "$(basename "$one")"
    done
)
```

Note that this will fail if you have linefeeds or possibly other odd characters in your filenames.  I can't think of a quick way out of this (I mean by doing this in a `find -exec`), since you need to calculate $deep differently for each level of directory.

Also, this is untested, and I'm not planning to test it.  If it gives you inspiration, that's great.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution that will make symbolic links but it will make hard links.

```
cp -rl $src $dst
```

Cons:

- it is harder to see if the file replaced in the tree
- the both trees    should be on the same filesystem